# Adding members in a subsite

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin, rest

I had successfully created sub sites using REST API and i set  'UseUniquePermissions': true  so that i can manage selected users as a member into the site i created , Now i'm wondering how can add a certain user to be a member in my site using REST API.?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two steps to do this.

Get your Group Name by its login name. Group is needed to add users in this group

```
/_api/web/sitegroups/GetByName('Your Group Name')
```

Now send a `POST` request in the following `URL` that will add your desired user to this group.

```
/_api/web/sitegroups('Group Id')/users
```

request body should be like following.

```
var data = {
    __metadata: {
        type: 'SP.User'
    },
    LoginName: 'Put here user login name'
}
```

Comment: or first i should create a group then add users on it..! copy.! cheers.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to create group to add user directly to specified subsite.
There is an endpoint for this:

```
/yoursubsite/_api/Web/RoleAssignments/AddRoleAssignment(principalId=xxx,roleDefId=1073741826)
```

You are doing `POST` request in context of `yoursubsite`.

`xxx` is ID of the user you want to add (can be also a groupId), and the `roleDefId` is based on the role you want to grant for this user:

```
Full Control    1073741829
Design          1073741828
Edit            1073741830
Contribute      1073741827
Read            1073741826
Limited Access  1073741825
View Only       1073741924
```

To list users, make a `GET` request: `/api/Web/SiteUsers`. Remeber, that response will list all users who are included in the root site. It doesn't mean, that these users have access to it.